# Exporting MySQL to CSV php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

lately i have been working on a database table ish website, whatever.

I am trying to make a button to download the MySQL table to and CSV file, but i get this error in the CSV file `str_replace() expects at least 3 parameters, 2 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\leif\export.php on line 37`

Button code:

```
<form action="export.php" method="post" name="export_excel">

            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
<button type="submit" id="export" name="export" class="btn btn-primary button-loading" data-loading-text="Laster...">Til CSV</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

here is the file that creates the CSV:

```
<?php


mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxxx", "xxxxx") or die (mysql_error ());

mysql_select_db("dom_oversikt") or die(mysql_error());

//header to give the order to the browser
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=domener.csv');

//select table to export the data
$select_table=mysql_query('select * from server1');
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_table);

if ($rows)
{
getcsv(array_keys($rows));
}
while($rows)
{
getcsv($rows);
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_table);
}

// get total number of fields present in the database
function getcsv($no_of_field_names)
{
$separate = '';


// do the action for all field names as field name
foreach ($no_of_field_names as $field_name)
{
if (preg_match('/\\r|\\n|,|"/', $field_name))
{
$field_name = '' . str_replace('', $field_name) . '';
}
echo $separate . $field_name;

//sepearte with the comma
$separate = ',';
}

//make new row and line
echo "\r\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Rather than messing around writing your own homebrew csv writer that will break the first time you have a comma in any of the data that you're exporting, why not read about PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP str_replace() function has 3 mandatory parameters, please check this

```
str_replace ($search, $replace, $subject);
```

For reference visit [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put 3 parameters in str_replace !

```
str_replace("String to search","String to replace with","Source String");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

> In addition, please don't use mysql_* function , it's removed now
>   you should use mysqli_* or PDO instead

Comment: It isn't deprecated, it has been completely removed.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the line 37 in your file. You are missing 3rd parameter that is the string on which you want to replace the character.

```
str_replace('', $field_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing 3rd parameter in the `str_replace`call.
In addiction, you have to catch first the result of regex, and to use `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match` to replace ALL the occurrences.

With `preg_replace`you can replace all in 1 line of code:

```
$field_name = preg_replace('/(\\r|\\n|,|")/','', $field_name);
```